# VBA Excel - Use Network path name not drive letter

Tags: vba, excel

How can I change the below drive letter from P to use network full path name instead?

I cant seem to figure it out

```
'Creating a FileSystemObject  
Public FSO As New FileSystemObject  
Sub DiskSpace()  
Dim drv As Drive  
Dim Space As Double  
Set drv = FSO.GetDrive("P:") ' Creating the the Drive object  
Space = drv.FreeSpace  
Space = Space / 1073741824 'converting bytes to GB  
Space = WorksheetFunction.Round(Space, 2) ' Rounding  
MsgBox "P: has free space = " & Space & " GB"  
End Sub
```

Comment: Free space applies to a drive not to a specific path.

Comment: I'd recommend avoiding using `Space` as a variable since it is also a VBA Function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify to suit:

```
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim DRV As Drive
    Dim FO As Folder
    Dim sPath As String

sPath = "\\RON-DODIER\Users"  'Network Folder Path

Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set FO = FSO.GetFolder(sPath)

Debug.Print FO.Drive.FreeSpace
```

You can also use the Drive property  of the File object, if that is more what you want, to determine the amount of free space.

Comment: How would I convert the number into GBs ? Tried but no luck

Comment: @Elixir The same as in your original.  Just divide the returned value by the number of bytes in a Gigabyte.  I don't understand why you are having a problem.

Comment: Thanks Ron , I'm doing the same conversion but the number is very different

Comment: @Elixir Then maybe the drive referred to by the UNC path is not `P:`

Comment: Hi, if I'm using `//` for the Network path is it ok? I'm not using `\\` because the system is unable to find the path, it is not mapped to the drive. The path is connecting to online source.